# modified jQuery API $.when() returns undefined when with timeouts

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I've tried to use the jQuery API's example of `when()` to make an example of my own using timeouts.

Theirs:

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
  // a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively.
  // Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]
  var data = a1[ 0 ] + a2[ 0 ]; // a1[ 0 ] = "Whip", a2[ 0 ] = " It"
  if ( /Whip It/.test( data ) ) {
    alert( "We got what we came for!" );
  }
});
```

Mine:

```
var fnOne = function(){

  setTimeout(function(){  return "one";    }, 1000);


};


var fnTwo = function(){

  setTimeout(function(){  return "two";    }, 5);

};


$(function(){

    $.when( fnOne(), fnTwo() ).then(function( a1, a2 ) {

      console.log(a1, a2);

   });


});
```

I just get `undefined undefined`. Why won't this work? Incidentally, it works when I remove the timeout. [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/nifusele/1/edit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.when()` requires arguments that are a deferred or promise.  It will then resolve itself when all those promises passed as arguments are resolved.  When you pass it something that is not a promise, `$.when()` really has no idea when it's done so can't do it's job.

If you really want to use `setTimeout()` with the promises API, then you probably want to wrap it so that it returns a promise that is resolved after the timer fires.  Then, you can use it just like the `$.ajax()` calls.

Here's a promise wrapper for `setTimeout()`.  It returns a promise that is resolved after the timer has fired and the callback has been called and the value it is resolved with is the return value from the callback:

```
function promiseSetTimeout(fn, t) {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
        d.resolve(fn());
    }, t);
    return d.promise();
}
```

Then, you could use `promiseSetTimeout()` with `$.when()`:

```
function fnOne() {
     return promiseSetTimeout(function(){  return "one";    }, 1000);
}

function fnTwo() {
     return promiseSetTimeout(function(){  return "one";    }, 1000);
}

$.when( fnOne(), fnTwo() ).then(function( a1, a2 ) {
  console.log(a1, a2);
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/HskLh/

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why in your example you return `d.promise()` while in @Felix Kling 's answer the entire deferred object is returned?

Comment: @thomas: it's actually better to return the promise only, otherwise the code that receives the deferred object could resolve it too. Just a small oversight from my side.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm sorry I don't quite understand, could you explain that a bit more? How does the code that receives the deferred (which?) not also just as easily resolve the promise? Thank you.

Comment: @thomas: because the promise doesn't have the API to do that. It only has `.done`, `.then`, etc, but it doesn't have `.resolve` or `.reject`. To resolve the promise, you need access to the deferred object. The API of the deferred object is a superset of the promise API.

Comment: @thomas - Felix has pretty much already answered your question about returning a promise instead of a deferred, but to summarize, the promise ONLY gets notifications of reject and resolve and progress.  The deferred can get those notifications AND can be told to resolve or reject.  If you only want someone to be able to monitor the events, not influence them, then it's generally better to return the promise, not the deferred as a general practice.

Answer (score 2):

> Why won't this work?

Because `fnOne` and `fnTwo` don't return a promise, they return `undefined`. The functions should look like:

```
var fnOne = function(){
  var deferred = new $.Deferred();

  setTimeout(function(){  deferred.resolve("one")   }, 1000);

  return deferred;
};
```

Otherwise, if you pass any other value than a promise to `$.when`, it will automatically create a resolved promise with that value. Also, returning a value from the callback you pass to `setTimeout` doesn't have any effect on the function that calls `setTimeout`.

Comment: Why don't you have to return `deferred` within the timeout? Won't it simply return immediately if it's not in the timeout'd function?

Comment: hi felix, could you reply to my comment. i am still curious about this. thank you.

Comment: That's the whole point. The deferred object/promise has to be returned immediately, so that the caller of `fnOne` gets a reference to it. Since you are not calling the `setTimeout` callback, you would not be able to access its return value anywhere.